# PHP Image Resize doesn't work

Tags: php, gd

I have a script to save an image two times, one for high quality and one for thumb. The moving of the image works but the resizing doesn't. Anybody have a clue? I have GD installed

```
$newImgName = RandomString(6) . '_' . rand(10, 99);

$newCoverImg = '../images/news/'. $newImgName .'.jpg';
$newThumbImg = '../images/news/'. $newImgName .'_thumb.jpg';

copy($_POST['article_cover'], $newCoverImg);
copy($_POST['article_cover'], $newThumbImg);

$percent = 0.5;

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($newThumbImg);
$newwidth = $width * $percent;
$newheight = $height * $percent;

$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($newThumbImg);

imagecopyresampled($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
```

Comment: None, display errors is on and yes GD is installed

Comment: what does imagecopyresampled return for ya?

Comment: The exact same width and height @NickMaroulis

Comment: true or false? if false try casting newwidth, newheight to ints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write **imagecopyresized** instead of **imagecopyresampled** your code should be like this

```
$newImgName = RandomString(6) . '_' . rand(10, 99);

$newCoverImg = '../images/news/'. $newImgName .'.jpg';
$newThumbImg = '../images/news/'. $newImgName .'_thumb.jpg';

copy($_POST['article_cover'], $newCoverImg);
copy($_POST['article_cover'], $newThumbImg);

$percent = 0.5;

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($newThumbImg);
$newwidth = $width * $percent;
$newheight = $height * $percent;

$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($newThumbImg);

imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
```

Comment: Used that in first place but doesn't work either

Comment: as you mentioned the file moving is working. The resizing code is fine. I dont think here is any problem. I am bit confused about your copu($_POST['article_cover'], $newCoverImg);
have your tried $_FILE instead of $_POST.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php